# Mongo: commandline admin auth fails

Tags: mongodb

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.0
connecting to: test
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.auth('admin', '******')
1
```

Then I can connect to other databases and run commands

Then I accidentally hit ctrl-C, so I try to login again.

```
$ mongo 
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.0
connecting to: test
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.auth('admin', '******')
0
```

I can no longer auth against the admin collection.  I assume this is because my previous login somehow didn't get cleared out, or is locked?  How do I fix that?

Comment: Found it!

Just needed to get rid of the lock file.

For me, this was here:

    /ap/mongo/data/db/mongod.lock

Comment: you can add this as an answer and accept it, so it may be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Just needed to get rid of the lock file. For me, this was here:

`/ap/mongo/data/db/mongod.lock`